# How can I cleanup NVIDIA files the File Repository folder - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I have noticed that NVIDIA files are making my Driver Store File Repository take up a whopping 16.2 GB. Clearly there is something wrong here.

I did some research, and I downloaded the suggested DriverStore.Explorer.v0.8. This confirmed my fears.

[image: lots of massive NVIDIA drivers]

Is there any way I can delete these but knowing which I can delete safely? I couldn't find any clear guidance on this.

FYI I'm running Windows 10 x64

Comment: run the tool as admin, select all old drivers and click on "delete packages"

Comment: See what version you have installed in device manager, then you can delete older versions

Answer (score 6):

I appreciate this question is a bit old, but I came across this question because I had exactly the same issue, with exactly the same version numbers as you do for all the old drivers.

My solution was to sort the drivers by version number, and delete all the Nvidia graphics drivers except the newest. I didn't need to use "force" for this so I'm happy those weren't in use.

My guess would be there was a bug in that particular version of the Nvidia installer which meant that loads of different unnecessary drivers were installed for devices you don't have - this is why the DriveStore Explorer doesn't recognise them as old drivers.

Comment: Interesting guess! They were all labeled with one version number for me as well. Could potentially explain why they weren't marked as old. Deleting them caused no harm for me either.

Answer (score 0):

The ones that are old, you can safely remove them by delete. Do not select force delete. This way, if a driver is in use, it wouldn't be deleted. You can do that for the devices that are active such as Nvidai GPU, which you can be sure of being used by launching Nv Control Panel.

The image shown in the question looks weird as it looks like all the NV drivers installed are same on the same date. I have not seen any such thing earlier. The best option is to uninstall the NV driver manually from Control Panel, select all the NV instances in the image above and remove them by clicking 'Delete Package'. Do a fresh NV Driver install using Driver's setup. For a typical user, it should be fine!

Comment: What I meant was try deleting them one by one without force option selected so that the driver currently in use is not deleted and rest could be deleted and space can be reclaimed.